# How to get the doc string attribute of a property?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, descriptor

When I was learning Python Descriptors I came across this example

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ''

    def fget(self):
        print("Getting: %s" % self._name)
        return self._name

    def fset(self, name):
        print("Setting: %s" % name)
        self._name = name.title()

    def fdel(self):
        print("Deleting: %s" %self._name)
        del self._name

    name = property(fget, fset, fdel, "I'm the property.")
```

which uses `property` function. The [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-pythondescriptors/index.html) says fourth parameter is *doc – docstring*,

```
p1 = Person()
p1.name = "Islam"
print(p1.name)
print(p1.name.doc)
del p1.name
```

but when I try to get to doc it raises

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'doc'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, since doc string is a magic attribute it should be in a [`double leading and trailing underscore`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) form. So, it's `__doc__` not `doc`.

Secondly, when you try to access `__doc__` from instance of the class, it will triggers the doc attribute of the actual object which in this case is a string. Instead, try to access the attribute from class object:

```
In [74]: Person.name.__doc__
Out[74]: "I'm the property."
```